# List all installed typings with tsd

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsd

Is there any way to print out all of the installed tsd typings in the command line?

Something like:

`$ tsd list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no commands to get the list via the `tsd` app.

That being said if you are using `--save` or `-s` when installing definitions:

```
tsd install jquery --save
```

Then the installed components will be listed within the tsd.json file. Here is the contents of one from a project of mine:

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "src/typings",
  "bundle": "src/typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "angularjs/angular.d.ts": {
      "commit": "6baa15a0d760170b4aeefab68d581a1ea4034aa6"
    },
    "jquery/jquery.d.ts": {
      "commit": "6baa15a0d760170b4aeefab68d581a1ea4034aa6"
    },
    "jasmine/jasmine.d.ts": {
      "commit": "581563c4684d405afec14260ba79a89a52666c09"
    }
  }
}
```

You can view the documentation for `tsd` [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd)